# SonarQube hangs on start at "o.s.s.s.RegisterQualityProfiles] Register Quality Profiles..."

Tags: sonarqube

My Sonar hangs when I restart it.

The last entries in the logfile are:

```
2014.07.08 11:02:23 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules...
2014.07.08 11:02:26 INFO  [org.sonar.INFO]  Register rules done: 3809 ms
2014.07.08 11:02:26 INFO  [o.s.s.s.RegisterQualityProfiles]  Register Quality Profiles...
```

Can I somehow bypass these steps or remove Quality Profiles manually when Sonar is stopped (maybe directly on the database?).

I had an issue importing quality profiles before (imported a ruleset but it was empty)

Comment: Please provide more informations. Which version ? Which plugins are installed ? Which database ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason myself:

Some rules of my custom quality profile where referencing plugins (PMD & checkstyle) which I hadn't installed (or not the right version at least). After installing these plugins (just put the jars in the plugins folder and restart), it worked.